How can I enable http (instead of https) for an Open API service in VS 2022?
When I am running debug at a project of open API service, it can start a browser with the port as specified in launchSettings.json.
{
  "profiles": {
    "Service": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:61050;http://localhost:61051"
    }
  }
}

I can see at the log that the application should be listening on both the https and http ports
Now listening on: https://localhost:61050
Now listening on: http://localhost:61051

Then, I can call my GET service endpoint https://localhost:61050/get-something, which is fine.
But when I tried to call the http (not https) one, it is not working with the following error
This page isn’t working
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

It looks like that http is disabled. How can I enable it?
I also tried to add the following code at Program.cs when configuring the service.
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 0);
});

In the log, I can see that it is listening on a random port now with http only (Although it is a bit weird that the browser does not pop up automatically when starting debug)
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:63364

When I tried to call http://localhost:63364/get-something, it failed with the same error.
To summarize,
my main questions is How can I enable http for my Open API service with a random port?
a minor question (which I am not sure if it is related or not) is Why builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel affects the behavior of browser pop-up?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Have you tried disabling  app.UseHttpsRedirection();? (var app = builder.Build();)

@Bishan No. I just tried to use it, it is still failing with the same error

You're using webhook, right? . To make a  request from https to http is impossible so you have to fake the request. I prefer to use Ngrok for this solution.

No. I am currently using nswag to generate the open api server code and tried to call it with a client (a browser) in debug mode.

You call an api with http ? Is that possible ?

any reason why it is not possible?
